# How to recolor an image using CoreGraphics?

Tags: ios, image-processing, core-graphics

I have a picture in shades of gray. Is it possible to recolor the image in shades of other (arbitrary) color? Something like on the picture below.

[image]

I think I can do that by accessing each pixel of the image and changing it as necessary, but I think that there might be a better way.

I would like to do all this using CoreGraphics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved the task using following code:

```
CGContextSaveGState(bitmapContext);
CGContextSetRGBFillColor(bitmapContext, red, green, blue, alpha);

CGContextTranslateCTM(bitmapContext, 0.0, contextHeight);
CGContextScaleCTM(bitmapContext, 1.0, -1.0);
CGContextDrawImage(bitmapContext, sourceImageRect, sourceImage);

CGContextSetBlendMode(bitmapContext, kCGBlendModeColor);
CGContextFillRect(bitmapContext, sourceImageRect);

CGContextRestoreGState(bitmapContext);

CGImageRef coloredImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(bitmapContext);
```

In this code `bitmapContext` is context created with `CGBitmapContextCreate`.

Comment: This has some weird artifacts sometimes, especially doing purple over white areas

Comment: @PsychoDad It might be. Do you know any workarounds for the issue?

Comment: haven't found any. It only seems to happen with purple on white areas. Bug in iOS is my guess.